# OpenSuse 13.2 - repo not-found

Tags: linux

При попытки установки `pattern devel_basis` вылазиет ошибка:

```
zypper install --type pattern devel_basis 
File '/content' not found on medium 'http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/13.2/repo/non-oss/'


zypper lr -d
#  | Alias                         | Name                               | Enabled | GPG Check | Refresh | Priority | Type   | URI                                                                                    | Service
---+-------------------------------+------------------------------------+---------+-----------+---------+----------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------
 1 | KDE:Qt                        | KDE:Qt                             | Yes     | (r ) Yes  | Yes     |   99     | rpm-md | http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/KDE:/Qt/openSUSE_Leap_42.2/                  |        
 2 | download.opensuse.org-non-oss | Main Repository (NON-OSS)          | Yes     | ( p) Yes  | Yes     |   99     | yast2  | http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/13.2/repo/non-oss/                           |        
 3 | download.opensuse.org-oss     | Main Repository (OSS)              | Yes     | ( p) Yes  | Yes     |   99     | yast2  | http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/13.2/repo/oss/                               |        
 4 | download.opensuse.org-oss_1   | Main Repository (Sources)          | Yes     | ( p) Yes  | Yes     |   99     | yast2  | http://download.opensuse.org/source/distribution/13.2/repo/oss/                        |        
 5 | download.opensuse.org-update  | Main Update Repository             | No      | ----      | Yes     |   99     | rpm-md | http://download.opensuse.org/update/13.2/                                              |        
 6 | openSUSE-13.2-0               | openSUSE-13.2-0                    | Yes     | ( p) Yes  | No      |   99     | yast2  | cd:///?devices=/dev/disk/by-id/ata-VMware_Virtual_IDE_CDROM_Drive_10000000000000000001 |        
 7 | openSUSE:Leap:42.2            | openSUSE:Leap:42.2                 | Yes     | (r ) Yes  | Yes     |   99     | yast2  | http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/leap/42.2/repo/oss/                          |        
 8 | repo-debug                    | openSUSE-13.2-Debug                | No      | ----      | Yes     |   99     | NONE   | http://download.opensuse.org/debug/distribution/13.2/repo/oss/                         |        
 9 | repo-debug-update             | openSUSE-13.2-Update-Debug         | No      | ----      | Yes     |   99     | NONE   | http://download.opensuse.org/debug/update/13.2/                                        |        
10 | repo-debug-update-non-oss     | openSUSE-13.2-Update-Debug-Non-Oss | No      | ----      | Yes     |   99     | NONE   | http://download.opensuse.org/debug/update/13.2-non-oss/                                |        
11 | repo-update-non-oss           | openSUSE-13.2-Update-Non-Oss       | No      | ----      | Yes     |   99     | rpm-md | http://download.opensuse.org/update/13.2-non-oss/                                      |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поддержка Opensuse 13.2 прекращена 17 января 2017 года. [пруф >>>](https://lists.opensuse.org/opensuse-security-announce/2017-01/msg00033.html)

Поэтому репу **non-oss** могли и выпилить.
Но причина может быть связа и с тем, несколько дней назад лежали все репы Opensuse для всех дистров, просто еще не успели поднять, так как не сильно актуально.

А вообще, пора бы и освежиться) хотя в вашем случае и **zypper dup** не спасет, только с нуля все устанавливать.

PS если у вас 13.2 x86, и вам нужна имено x86, посмотрите в сторону
[openSUSE Tumbleweed >>>](http://download.opensuse.org/tumbleweed/iso/)